# Многопоточная запись в файл в python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть огромный лист B и огромный словарь A. Для каждого элемента B нужно проверить наличие его в A и в случае наличия записать в файл.
Я сделал это таким образом и получаю неверный результат работы.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def func(i):
    if i in A:
        ff.write(str(A[i]) + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = {2 * x : 0 for x in range(5000000)}
    B = [x for x in range(10000000)]
    ff = open("task.del", "w")
    pool =  Pool(4)
    pool.map(func, B)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

В результате в файле неверное количество ответов (должно быть около 5 миллионов +- 1, а получается, к примеру на 4 процессах 4997120). Работает эта система, к тому же, еще и дольше чем однопоточная. Я понимаю, что какие-то накладки по скорости будут, но в данном случае, подозреваю, проблема в постоянном перехвате дескриптора файла для записи. Посоветуйте, как лучше.

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы сначала использовать потоки вместо процессов: `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` ? Еще, я бы предложил, чтобы каждый процесс писал в свой файл, а после вы бы их объединили в один, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077437/5909792

Comment: К сожалению, я не очень понял чем поточный вариант лучше обычного поточного (мультитрединг), который, судя по обрывочным статьям, упирается в глобальный лок и то ли вообще работает медленнее, чем однопоточный вариант, то ли не дает нормального ускорения. Про вариант записи в несколько файлов думал, выглядит как костыли, например, если мы пишем не просто текстовик, а какой-то формат, где конкатенация 4 файлов не равна одному, скажем сжимаем при этом еще информацию.

Comment: У меня поточный вариант завершился намного быстрее, потестируйте три варианта: в один поток, в несколько потоков и в несколько процессов. `"Про вариант записи в несколько файлов думал, выглядит как костыли"` это зависит от задачи, в текущей задаче это было бы нормально

Comment: В Google Colab у меня получается 4998340 причём неважно в сколько потоков пул инициализировать. Интересно, интересно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу только предложить всё же писать в файл в одном потоке, а данные для записи генерировать в несколько потоков. Тогда всё нормально работает. Когда питон создаёт потоки он **копирует** в каждый поток все переменные основного потока и, видимо, поэтому с дескриптором файла получается какая-то накладка, он так не умеет работать, чтобы один дескриптор (вернее его копия) работал из нескольких потоков сразу.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def func(i):
    if i in A:
        return A[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = {2 * x : 0 for x in range(5000000)}
    B = [x for x in range(10000000)]
    with open("task.del", "w") as ff:
        with Pool(4) as pool:
            for r in pool.map(func, B):
                if r != None:
                    ff.write(str(r) + "\n")
```

Comment: Но я же создаю процесс, а не поток.

Comment: @MiroslavMorozov Если правильно помню, питону это без разницы. Всё-равно GIL не даёт ничего нормально делать, только всё копировать и отдельно запускать.

Answer (score -1):

Что конкретно многопоточно?

Можно например, данные формировать в отдельном процессе, и выдавать их по мере формирования, а в Главном процессе получать их и записывать в файл.

Или можно многопоточно формировать сразу все данные, а потом их записывать однопоточно.

И не следует пытатся многопоточно записывать в сам файл.

```
t1 = time.monotonic()  # 0 сек
A = {2 * x : 0 for x in range(5000000)}
B = [x for x in range(10000000)]
t2 = time.monotonic()  # + 2.0 сек
s = A.keys() & set(B)
t3 = time.monotonic()  # + 1.3 сек
s = '\n'.join(map(str, s))
t4 = time.monotonic()  # + 1.7 сек
with open('task.del', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
t5 = time.monotonic()  # + 0.6 сек
print((t2 - t1), (t3 - t2), (t4 - t3), (t5 - t4))
```

Comment: Не очень понял что здесь происходит. Вы заиспользовали map, а многопоточность то где? Разве обычный map исполняется в несколько потоков?

Comment: "И не следует пытатся многопоточно записывать в сам файл." Эх. Второй вариант не очень хорош по памяти, а вот первый как раз то, что мне нужно, спасибо.